# Systemd `journalctl` - Unable to change default $PAGER

Tags: bash, systemd, systemd-journald, pager

I'm on Arch Linux.

I came across some new pager software called [OV](https://github.com/noborus/ov) and installed it. It has more features than `less` and I like it so I want to set it as my default pager.

I added the following to my .bashrc:

```bash
export PAGER=/usr/bin/ov
```

Most programs are respecting this environment variable (e.g. `man`), but for some reason `journalctl` does not. In googling the problem, I came across another variable `SYSTEMD_PAGER`. I expected that setting this environment variable would solve the issue, but it does not.

Even with:

```bash
export PAGER=/usr/bin/ov
export SYSTEMD_PAGER=/usr/bin/ov
```

That did not work. I then tried passing the var explicitly:

```bash
PAGER=/usr/bin/ov journalctl
SYSTEMD_PAGER=/usr/bin/ov journalctl
```

No luck. `journalctl` **always** uses the default `less` pager.

I did find one way to force it:

```bash
journalctl | ov
```

This works, but I don't want to have to pipe it every time. It should respect the environment variable.

I have looked at the `journalctl` documentation, but cannot find an answer.

Is it possible to configure the default pager for systemd `journalctl`? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're seeing the effects of `SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE` in action. From [`man journalctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/journalctl.1.html#ENVIRONMENT):

```
$SYSTEMD_PAGER
   Pager to use when --no-pager is not given; overrides $PAGER.
   If neither $SYSTEMD_PAGER nor $PAGER are set, a set of
   well-known pager implementations are tried in turn, including
   less(1) and more(1), until one is found. If no pager
   implementation is discovered no pager is invoked. Setting
   this environment variable to an empty string or the value
   "cat" is equivalent to passing --no-pager.

   Note: if $SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE is not set, $SYSTEMD_PAGER (as
   well as $PAGER) will be silently ignored.
```

And:

```
$SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE
   Takes a boolean argument. When true, the "secure" mode of the
   pager is enabled; if false, disabled. If $SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE
   is not set at all, secure mode is enabled if the effective
   UID is not the same as the owner of the login session, see
   geteuid(2) and sd_pid_get_owner_uid(3). In secure mode,
   LESSSECURE=1 will be set when invoking the pager, and the
   pager shall disable commands that open or create new files or
   start new subprocesses. When $SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE is not set
   at all, pagers which are not known to implement secure mode
   will not be used. (Currently only less(1) implements secure
   mode.)
```

So this should work:

```
SYSTEMD_PAGERSECURE=true PAGER=/usr/bin/ov journalctl
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Clearly I should have spent more time on the documentation, I missed this variable.

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge you can not change the `journalctl` pager by using env variables.

The best way is to use an `alias` in bash:

`alias alias_name="command_to_run"`

so in your case it could be:

`alias journalov="journalctl --no-pager | ov"`

The `--no-pager` flag gets rid of the internal pager and should be faster.

Now your new command would be `journalov`, which you can change to your liking.