# Default output mode for journalctl

Tags: linux, systemd, logs, journalctl

Is there a way to make, for example, `--output=cat` the default output mode for a `journalctl`?

Can't find something in `journald.conf(5)` or `journalctl(1)`?

P.S. shell alias is too obvious. I'm looking for some options to set.

Comment: what should `--output=cat` do? What do you expect it to do?  Normally, `journalctl` buffers the output by using the `more`  pager. So if you want to dump the output of `journalctl` without paginating it then you can use  `--no-pager`, basically the same as `journalctl | cat -`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [Systemd `journalctl` - Unable to change default $PAGER](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/730521/414186)

Comment: @ValentinBajrami You could've read the man before. `--output` control how journal records are printed. It's a set of pre-defined formats and fields listed to print. The question isn't about the pager.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon I'm not trying to change the pager.

Comment: Alias sounds like the easiest approach. Or filing a feature request here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues

Comment: I’m also looking for how to change the default format without resorting to aliases. Surprised there seems to be no way to configure journalctl…

Comment: The question is asking for using `journalctl -o cat` as `journalctl` without using `alias` which is not effective under `sudo`. I need it too.